# Microsoft Excel - Copy entire row from different sheet based on multiple criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, macros

Okay, I've been trying to find this answer for a while and I can't quite get it using formulas specifically as it would require more than the formula bar could hold and I have zero experience with MACROs.

Rules:

Rule 1. Fox/Golf/Hotel!A4 will always be the 1st and A34 will always be the 31st of the month (A33=30th, A32=29th (when applicable), A31=28th)

Rule 1a. Fox!A36:A37 and Fox!A39:A40 will never be a Date

Rule 1a.1. Fox!A36 will be "Super-1-16" and Fox!A37 will be "Super-17-31"

Rule 1a.2. Fox!A39 will be "Primary" and Fox!A40 will be "Supernumerary"

Rule 1b. Golf/Hotel!A36:A37 will never be a Date.

Rule 1b.1. Golf/Hotel!A36 will be "Super-1-16" and Golf/Hotel!A37 will be "Super-17-31"

Rule 2. Corresponding Dates on Alpha/Bravo/Charlie/Delta! could be any cell B3:B400

Rule 3. "Position" is a variant in "Alpha/Bravo/Charlie/Delta!A3:A400" but will always be a constant for "Fox/Golf/Hotel!" cells (See below for constants).

Rule 3a. Fox! "Position" designations:

1. B2="OOD" and should cover C4:G34.
2. I2="AOOD" and should cover J4:M34.
3. O2="DD" and should cover P4:S34.
4. A35="OOD SUPERNUMERARY" and should cover C36:G37.
5. A38="CDO" and should cover C39:G40.
6. I35="ADNCO SUPERNUMERARY" and should cover J36:J37.
7. O35="DD SUPERNUMERARY" and should cover P36:S37.

Rule 3b. Golf/Hotel! "Position" Designations:

1. B2="DNCO" and should cover C4:F34.
2. H2="ADNCO" and should cover I4:L34.
3. N2="Rover 1" and should cover O4:R34.
4. T2="Rover 2" and should cover U4:X34.
5. A35="DNCO SUPERNUMERARY" and should cover C36:F37.
6. H35="ADNCO SUPERNUMRARY" and should cover C39:L40.
7. N35="ROVER 1 SUPERNUMRARY" and should cover J36:R37.
8. T35="ROVER 2 SUPERNUMRARY" and should cover P36:X37.

Rule 4. The following cells should dictate which sheet info is copied from:

Rule 4a. Fox!(B will dictate C:G.  I will dictate J:M.  O will dictate P:S)

Rule 4a.1.  B4:B34 (if Fox!B4="A", Fox!B2=Alpha!A136, and Alpha!B136="May 1" then Fox!C4:G4 = Alpha!C136:G136).

Rule 4a.2.  I4:I34 (if Fox!I7="D", Fox!I2=Delta!A98, and Delta!B98="May 4" then Fox!J4:M4 = Delta!C98:F98).

Rule 4a.3.  O4:O34.

Rule 4a.4.  B36:B37 (if Fox!B36="C", Fox!A35=Charlie!A250, and Charlie!B250="May 1-16" then Fox!C36:G36 = Charlie!C250:G250).

Rule 4a.5.  B39:B40 (if Fox!B40="B", Fox!A38=Bravo!A123, and Bravo!B123="Supernumerary" then Fox!C40:G40 = Bravo!C123:G250).

Rule 4a.6.  I36:I37.

Rule 4a.7.  O36:O37.

Rule 4b. Golf/Hotel!(B will dictate C:F.  H will dictate I:L.  N will dictate O:R.  T will dictate U:X)

Rule 4b.1.  B4:B34.

Rule 4b.2.  H4:H34.

Rule 4b.3.  N4:N34.

Rule 4b.4.  T4:T34.

Rule 4b.5.  B36:B37.

Rule 4b.6.  H39:H40.

Rule 4b.7.  N36:N37.

Rule 4b.8.  T36:T37.

I need to copy cells from "Alpha/Bravo/Charlie/Delta!B3:G400" to corresponding cells in "Fox/Golf/Hotel!" based on Fox/Golf/Hotel! Dates (Fox/Golf/Hotel!A4:A40) and the set "Position" fields in rule 3.

EDIT TO HOPEFULLY MAKE THE REQUEST LESS CONFUSING:

This is a monthly roster that I am in charge of and am just trying to make it easier for everyone involved.

Sheets Fox!, Golf!, and Hotel! correspond to specific buildings we have and Sheets Alpha!, Bravo!, Charlie, and Delta! correspond to our sections.

Fox/Golf/Hotel! is filled in by pulling information from Alpha/Bravo/Charlie/Delta!.  I would like to make this automated so we don't have to copy and paste every month.

I tried to make a formula but nesting that many IFANDs couldn't fit.

I understand that there is a lot of information above but I will try to summarize it as best as I am capable.

For sheet Fox!,

Step 1.  I need to use Cell B4:B34 to determine which sheet to pull information from (If B4=A pull from sheet Alpha!.  If B4=B pull from sheet Bravo!.  If B4=C pull from sheet Charlie!.  If B4=D pull from sheet Delta!.)

Step 2.  After the sheet is determined, I need to use Cell B2 to locate a match on Alpha/Bravo/Charlie/Delta!A3:A400.

Step 3.  Once the match is found, I need to use Cell A4:A34 to locate a match on Alpha/Bravo/Charlie/Delta!B3:B400

Step 4.  Once both matches are found on the same row, I need to copy Cells Alpha/Bravo/Charlie/Delta!C3:G400.

Examples for Fox! specifically:

Example 1.  If Fox!B4="A", and Fox!B2=Alpha!A136, and Alpha!B136="May 1" then Fox!C4:G4 = Alpha!C136:G136.

Example 2.  If Fox!B4="B", and Fox!B2=Bravo!A136, and Bravo!B136="May 1" then Fox!C4:G4 = Bravo!C136:G136.

Example 3.  If Fox!B4="C", and Fox!B2=Charlie!A136, and Charlie!B136="May 1" then Fox!C4:G4 = Charlie!C136:G136.

Example 4.  If Fox!B4="D", and Fox!B2=Delta!A136, and Delta!B136="May 1" then Fox!C4:G4 = Delta!C136:G136.

Examples for Golf/Hotel! specifically:

Example 1.  If Golf!B4="A", and Golf!B2=Alpha!A136, and Alpha!B136="May 1" then Golf!C4:F4 = Alpha!C136:F136.

Example 2.  If Hotel!B4="B", and Hotel!B2=Bravo!A136, and Bravo!B136="May 1" then Golf!C4:F4 = Bravo!C136:F136.

Example 3.  If Golf!B4="C", and Golf!B2=Charlie!A136, and Charlie!B136="May 1" then Golf!C4:F4 = Charlie!C136:F136.

Example 4.  If Hotel!B4="D", and Hotel!B2=Delta!A136, and Delta!B136="May 1" then Hotel!C4:F4 = Delta!C136:F136.

Easy to do for each individual example, but I need all 4 examples to be active in every cell on the respective pages.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because ,, it has so many information has messed up the issue,, unable to realize the need of the OP!

Comment: You should be very specific when asking. I mean, other users should be able to use your question to solve their problem. Generalize your  problem and ask one thing at a time. Give examples when applicable.

Comment: I updated the post, I left the original post in there but the bottom half is, hopefully, a better breakdown of what I'm asking for

Comment: It is still hard to understand, perhaps a mockup of your data and what the output should look like would help. One way to possibly shorten your formulas is to use `indirect()`.

Comment: That's the issue @gns100, I don't know how create a formula that complex.  I've nested formulas to pull from a different sheet/workbook before, but all of the information was being pulled from the same sheet from set rows/columns.  Setting a formula to pull from one of four sheets based on one cells criteria, then search that sheet for two different columns that match specific cell criteria from the first sheet is beyond my capabilities.

Answer (score 2):

No offence dude but worst phrased question ever! Also, formatting!

TL;DR, here's what I think you need

Put this in C4, it will translate the A to D into the sheet name.

```
=CHOOSE(CODE(B4)-CODE("A")+1,"Alpha!","Bravo!","Charlie!","Delta!")
```

Now in D4 we will calculate the index or row number in your chosen sheet where the B2 match occurs

```
=MATCH($B$2$, INDIRECT(C4 & "A3:A400"),0)
```

Now in E4 we will link to the values in the other sheet on the condition if A4 matches with B column:index D4 in the other sheet

```
=IF(A4 = INDEX(INDIRECT(C4 & "B3:B400"),D4), *link to cells in C to G cells*, *return blanks*)
```

So finally this goes in E4:I4 as an array formula (select E4 to I4, press F2, paste in the formula below, and press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER - enter only will not work). A single array formula will now occupy multiple cells in E4:I4: (note in office 365, you can enter the formula in E4 only and it will spill over into I4)

```
=IF(A4 = INDEX(INDIRECT(C4 & "B3:B400"),D4), INDEX(INDIRECT(C4 & "C3:C400"),D4):INDEX(INDIRECT(C4 & "G3:G400"),D4), "")
```

Comment: INDIRECT uses text to construct a reference. While flexible, Excel is unable to determine a dependency tree with refs based on INDIRECT, since the text reference can change at any time. The knock on affect is this cell becomes volatile i.e. it will recalculate wiith any small change in the workbook. If you use many INDIRECTS in a large workbook things will become slow quickly. There are ways around this using CHOOSE in C4 to return a reference e.g. `=CHOOSE(CODE($B$4$)-CODE("A")+1,Alpha!A3:G400,Bravo!A3:G400,Charlie!A3:G400,Delta!A3:G400)` followed by e.g. `=INDEX(C4,,1)` to return column A

Comment: A valiant effort! @mobus